# ReplicatorG Installation on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: apt, ppa

I have used ReplicatorG http://replicat.org/installation-linux to generate 3D printing files for a number of years. I have had to upgrade to 18.04 to support my Ryzen hardware, as this old code/ PPA was not written to support release files what is the best way to install this code on a 18.04 platform. I have found ways --allow-unauthenticated from a recognized repo , nothing on forcing from a PPA though. There are no signs that any more work will be done on the PPA to update it, if it's been sitting there since 12.0. Any insights appreciated in advance .

Answer (score 0):

According to their website you need to [download application](http://replicat.org/download):

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/replicatorg/replicatorg-0040-linux.tgz
```

And then [install it](http://replicat.org/installation-linux).

```
tar -xf replicatorg-0040-linux.tgz
cd replicatorg-0040/
```

It seems that it needs access to serial ports, so you should add your user to *dialout* group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER
```

Then log-out and log-in again and try to run ReplicatorG executable:

```
./replicatorg
```

[image: ReplicatorG on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS]

**Note:** I'm not sure about Java. On my system it started normally using default OpenJDK (*java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64*). If it does not work for you with real hardware, then you can install Sun/Oracle JDK. But I hope that this is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Turns out the url to the PPA in the installation instructions was broken. Once I discovered it now lives at google code, helped clear the fog. I wasn't only not getting the release file I wasn't getting the code either. Thanks again.